# GZIP compression not working in IE 8 ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, gzip

I'm using IIS6 and Windows 2003 server where I enabled gzip compression for my MVC project. I thought I got it working, but once I tested in IE it did not work.  I feels like it does not recognize the gzip compression or something.  It works fine in Fire Fox (version 13).

Do I need to configure something?

I do a HTTP post to get some data.

Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2012 21:33:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

If you need anything else please let know.

Thanks

Comment: Did you enabled gzip **and** deflate compression in your IIS?

Comment: I believe I did.  The compression is working in Fire Fox.  I got the header above from fiddler.  Trying to figure out why it did not work in IE8.  I feel I have not configured IIS correctly or something.

Comment: Hi @Tesh, Did you solve this issue? I am facing the same. I am getting compressed aspx response when browsing from Chrome. But from IE11 its not getting compressed data. IE 11 request has proper Accept Encoding.

Answer (score 1):

IIS does not perform HTTP compression on "dynamic" resources by default, only "static" files. This is because it caches the compressed results in IIS's temporary files directory, whereas dynamic content compression means it has to compress it every time its requested, which can burden the server if it's handling a lot of requests.

I also note that you're using IIS6 which is very antiquated at this point, but check out the documentation here: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/502ef631-3695-4616-b268-cbe7cf1351ce.mspx?mfr=true